# NumPy random.shuffle function

Tags: python, random, numpy, shuffle

I ran into something strange with `numpy.random.shuffle` function

```
from numpy import arange
from numpy.random import shuffle

a = arange(5)
b = a
c = a[:]

shuffle(c)
```

`a` and `b` all changes with `c`. Actually no matter I `shuffle()` which variable, the other two all changes with it. I thought when I use slice copy the original variable should be independent. Did I miss something? How can I protect the original variable from being changed?

Comment: Using a slice makes a copy for ordinary lists, but not necessarily for all types.  You have to read the documentation for any kind of object to use to see if slicing makes a copy or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Basic slicing documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing):

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

Use [ndarray.copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html#numpy-ndarray-copy) or [numpy.copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) to get copy.

Answer (score 1):

Using `c = a.copy()` can help you.